# Where to write javascript codes in ProcessMaker 4?

Tags: processmaker

I installed ProcessMaker 4 and find it very different from version 3. I am searching for the place to write my javascript code like this(as the way we used to write in version 3)

```
$('#submitAdd').click(function(){
    let price=$("#price").getValue(j,9);
    $("#gridListExpenses").setValue(price,j,30);
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Never used any version of processmaker other than 4 but from what I have read it has changed quite a bit.
From your script I pressume you wish to set a value in a form variable when some other value changes.
For this sort of functionality you should use watchers. Which in turn have their code defined just as any other script in the Designer>Scripts section.
Hope this point you in the correct direction.